# How to scan only dis,flt files

Tags: java, filechooser

I want to use only with `JFileChooser` I need to scan only dis,flt files:
I have code like this:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter xmlfilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
 "dis files (*.dis)", "dis");
FileNameExtensionFilter xmlfilter2 = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
 "flt files (*.flt)", "flt");
   chooser.setFileFilter(xmlfilter);
   chooser.setFileFilter(xmlfilter2);
   chooser.setDialogTitle("Open a file");

chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    java.io.File f= chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

In the filter it show that but it didnt scan this file why?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `addChoosableFileFilter`:

```
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(xmlfilter);
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(xmlfilter2);
```